# In Couchbase, does add ing a view to a design document trigger recalculation of all the views?

Tags: couchbase

This is the behaviour in CouchDB. Couchbase, however, does not allow editing of production views and so I'm guessing it wouldn't recalculate all views in a design document if another view is added to it.

Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To quote from the [admin guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#view-operation):

> All the views within a single design document are updated when the update to a single view is triggered. For example, a design document with three views will update all three views simultaneously when just one of these views is updated.